# UITableView in UIPageViewController in NavigationController with Page Control

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have the following set up:

UINavigationController -> UIPageViewController-> UITableViewController/UIViewController/UIViewController

my UIPageViewController looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class DailyRoutinePageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    var pages = [UIViewController]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self

        self.navigationItem.title = getActiveUserName()

        let page1: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("dailyRoutinePage1")
        let page2: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("dailyRoutinePage2")
        let page3: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("dailyRoutinePage3")

        pages.append(page1)
        pages.append(page2)
        pages.append(page3)

        setViewControllers([page1], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func buttonKontakte(sender: AnyObject) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("careTaker")
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex = pages.indexOf(viewController)!
        let previousIndex = abs((currentIndex - 1) % pages.count)
        return pages[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex = pages.indexOf(viewController)!
        let nextIndex = abs((currentIndex + 1) % pages.count)
        return pages[nextIndex]
    }

    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return pages.count
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

}
```

this works fine. I can scroll through all pages. Now I want to add a Page Control. I can add a Page Control to the UIPageView's. But how can I add one to the UITableViewController? And when I scroll through the pages the Page Control scroll with the pages. How can I make it stand still?

An other problem: The PageViewController doesn't respect the navigation title bar. So there is content behind the Naviagtion bar at the top. How can I fix this?

Comment: You will need to move your content down by 64 (using constraints) to respect the navigation bar

Comment: Hey, I cant add constraints to a UITableViewController. How can I add constraints to the whole view?

Comment: I would suggest that you use a UIViewController instead, and add a UITableView inside of it. The table view would be constrained to leading, trailing, and bottom. Then, it's top constraint would be 64, to account for the navigation bar.